# Whoops, looks like something went wrong

Tags: php, laravel

Before we get into this please, I can't stress this enough I don't know ANYTHING about Laravel so any help is very much appreciated and I'm always interested in learning.

Currently I am getting an issue that says this when I go to my website.

> Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

The issue has happened since I installed Laravel onto my server, through looking up some things I have learned that I am missing a file called `.env` please note that I am not familiar with WHAT this files does either all I know is that within my application it is in fact missing.

I seen some videos ([here](https://youtu.be/DPDa43vULrM?t=102)) which explain a little about `.env` how ever he pulls up a console in this video which I also don't know how to do.

So all around, I'm just in a giant mess trying to understand this platform, any help relating to my issue would be incredible or even a page where I can learn how to solve issues like this for future reference.

After looking over the wikipedia page it has no direct reference to how to solve these types of issues, so I of course got lost.

Comment: Set the debug option to true in `config/app.php` - this error could appear for any number of reasons, you need to turn debugging on to see the actual error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've uploaded your project to your server through git then there'll be a `.env.example` file or if through ftp then both `.env` and `.env.example`.

1. Rename the `.env.example` file to `.env` if there is not any already
2. In your `.env` file update these variables

   ```
   APP_ENV=production
   APP_KEY=some_gibberish_here
   ```
3. Save the `.env` file and reload your server.
4. If you've uploaded your project through git then run this command in your project folder via ssh session `composer install`

Hopefully this would fix your issue